# Can't access index of numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, multidimensional-array

My problem is probably quite trivial but I don't find the solution anywhere so I ask you anyway. As you can see in this code snippet I create a random integer called *index* and then I would like to access the element at this index (test_res is a 2-dim numpy array). I get the error message `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'`. Wierdly enough, this exact thing does work when I type it in the console:

```
index=random.randrange(0,10000)
network.test_res[index]
```

returns correctly `array([1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)`
But in this function I only get the error message and I don't understand why. What have I done differently? I am probably missing something fairly obvious so please excuse me and thank you in advance.

Here's my code snippet:

```
def test_predict(self):
        """ test some random numbers from the test part of the data set """
        index = random.randrange(0,10000) # there are 10000 images in the test part of the data set
        """ the actual result stored in the data set 
            It's represented as a list of 10 elements one of which being 1, the rest 0 """
        num_pixels = self.test_img.shape[0] * self.test_img.shape[1]
        correct_res = np.where(self.test_res[index] == 1) 
        predicted_res = np.argmax(self.model.predict(self.test_img[index].reshape(-1, num_pixels)), axis = 1)

        if correct_res != predicted_res:
            print("Error in predict ! \
                  index = ", index, " predicted result = ", predicted_res, " correct result = ", correct_res)
        else:
            print("alright")
```

Edit: This is the entire code:

```
# import random for tests
import random

# import keras and the MNIST dataset
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from keras.utils import np_utils

# import matplotlib to show pictures
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# numpy is necessary since keras uses numpy arrays
import numpy as np

class mnist_network():
    def __init__(self):
        """ load data, create and train model """
        # load data
        (X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
        # flatten 28*28 images to a 784 vector for each image
        num_pixels = X_train.shape[1] * X_train.shape[2]
        X_train = X_train.reshape((X_train.shape[0], num_pixels)).astype('float32')
        X_test = X_test.reshape((X_test.shape[0], num_pixels)).astype('float32')
        # normalize inputs from 0-255 to 0-1
        X_train = X_train / 255
        X_test = X_test / 255
        # one hot encode outputs
        y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train)
        y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test)
        num_classes = y_test.shape[1]


        # create model
        self.model = Sequential()
        self.model.add(Dense(num_pixels, input_dim=num_pixels, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
        self.model.add(Dense(num_classes, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='softmax'))
        # Compile model
        self.model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

        # train the model
        self.model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=10, batch_size=200, verbose=2)

        self.train_img = X_train
        self.train_res = y_train
        self.test_img = X_test
        self.test_res = y_test


    def test_all(self):
        """ evaluates the success rate using all the test data """
        scores = self.model.evaluate(self.test_img, self.test_res, verbose=0)
        print("Baseline Error: %.2f%%" % (100-scores[1]*100))

    def predict(self, img, show=False):
        """ img has to be a 784 vector """
        """ predicts the number in a picture (vector) """
        if show:
            # show the picture
            plt.imshow(img, cmap='Greys')
            plt.show()

        num_pixels = img.shape[1] * img.shape[2]
        # the actual number
        res_number = np.argmax(self.model.predict(img.reshape(-1,num_pixels)), axis = 1)

        """ the probabilities """
        res_probabilities = self.model.predict(img.reshape(-1,num_pixels))

        return res_number[0]    # res_number is a list containing one element

    def test_predict(self):
        """ test some random numbers from the test part of the data set """
        index = random.randrange(0,10000) # there are 10000 images in the test part of the data set
        """ the actual result stored in the data set 
            It's represented as a list of 10 elements one of which being 1, the rest 0 """
        num_pixels = self.test_img.shape[0] * self.test_img.shape[1]
        correct_res = np.where(self.test_res[index] == 1) 
        predicted_res = np.argmax(self.model.predict(self.test_img[index].reshape(-1, num_pixels)), axis = 1)

        if correct_res != predicted_res:
            print("Error in predict ! \
                  index = ", index, " predicted result = ", predicted_res, " correct result = ", correct_res)
        else:
            print("alright")



network = mnist_network()
network.test_predict()
```

Comment: Could you add the error description (line number etc.) Currently it's very difficult to replicate the problem because we don't have access to `self` and all the attached functions to run it

Comment: My guess is that somewhere else in the code you call `.index()` method of the python `list` on `np.array`.

Comment: I think @Ardweaden is probably right. The code as written shouldn't cause that error — you never try to access an `index` attribute here. The error you'd get from a bad indexing operation would be `IndexError`, `TypeError`, or `KeyError`, not `AttributeError`. So the thing causing the error is probably somewhere else in your code!

Comment: @Nathan Thank you for your answers. I edited my post to add the entire code. I still don't see the problem though.

Comment: Check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49649836/tensorflow-dnnclassifier-error-wile-training-numpy-ndarray-has-no-attribute-in